# Sorting Array in O(n) complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was asked an interesting question at my interview at Atrenta. It was to sort an array with an complexity of O(n) which I said is not possible but he insisted it is, even after the interview.

It is like this.

You have an array, lets say : [1,0,1,0,1,1,0] and this needs to be sorted. What ever has to be done within the array (in the sense no other data structure involved.

I haven't and I don't think it is possible to do any sort with an complexity of O(n). The best I could think of is O(n * log n) and my knowledge comes from Wikipedia.

Please give me your ideas and well a way to do it if you know.

Comment: Read the rest of the Wikipedia article on sorting. `O(n log n)` only need apply to _comparison_ based sorts, not e.g. radix sort.

Comment: This has been asked and answered numerous times on SO, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655659/on-sorting-algorithm-possible?rq=1.

Comment: any constraint on the data set can result in a simplification of the algorithm. Here, if data are 0 and 1, a bucket sort is O(n+k), which is O(n+2), which is O(n)

Comment: a counting sort would work too.

Comment: Feeling soooo horrible and ashamed... :D You guys are right! So a restriction would have done the magic.

Comment: @A.Webb : After you said, I saw it. Actually didn't take it much serious nor was I in lectures and completely missed the point... Yet it is some thing you can think and answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example there are only two different values in the array, so you could use counting sort:

```
zero_count = 0
for value in array:
    if value == 0:
        zero_count += 1
for i in 0 ... zero_count:
    array[i] = 0
for i in zero_count ... array.size:
    array[i] = 1
```

Radix sorts are a family of more generally applicable O(n) sorts.

It is *comparison sorts* that require Omega(n * log n) comparisons on average and hence cannot run in worst-case or average-case linear time.

Comment: that looks like python, so for beauty of short code, array.count(0) does it. (however, for big O measure, a for loop is more explicit, of course)

Comment: @njzk2: yeah, it's a Python-influenced pseudo-code. In actual Python, `zeros = array.count(0); return [0] * zeros + [1] * (len(array) - zeros)` would do it but like you say that doesn't make the complexity very explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Traverse the array from both ends and Swap 1's and 0's when needed.Runs in O(n) but has all the if conditions(*bruteforce like approach.probably not the expected answer*) ;)

```
int i = 0 ;
int j = array.size -1 ;
for ( i = 0 ; i < j ; ) {

    if( array[i] == 1) {
        if( array[j] == 0 ) {
            array[j] = 1 ; array[i] = 0 ; //Swap 
            i++; j--; 
            continue;
        }
        //else
            j--;
            continue;

    }
   //else
        if( array[j] == 0 ) {
            i++; 
            continue;
        }

        //else 
            i++ ;
            j--;            
}
```

Comment: I think Steve's answer using counting sort was the expected answer there

Comment: Both works! this is kind of sort, that is called counting I guess!

Comment: both answers are correct and are classified in the complexity of O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a binary array, It is possible to solve it with complexity of O(n) using the two pointer method.
The code will look like this :

```
void sort01(int arr[], int n){
int i = 0, j = n - 1;
while (i <= j){
    if (arr[i] == 0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        j--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: swap() is one more complexity about this algorithm not being classified as O(n).  And this is wrong because it will not order in the second loop, creating an exit like this: {0,0,1,1,1,0,1}